# Not getting any result

Tags: python, selenium

What am I doing wrong, I am not getting any result. In theory if I just print posts it shows me some results?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver= webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/farza/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/")

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="list_table"]""")
posts= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("data")
for post in posts:
    print post
```

Comment: What result are you trying to get exactly? Update the question with the revelant  _HTML_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page is loaded an animation is hiding the information you need. You have to wait in your code till this animation is finished. Just to test your code you can click the "Continue To Side" text manualy. With a slight modification in your code you will have result:

```
datas = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="list_table"]""")
print ("data")
for data in datas:
    print (data.text)
posts= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'data')]/td")
print ("post")
for post in posts:
    print (post.text)
```

Part of the result will be:

[image]